# Power Query - Pivot Table / Group by specific filters

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

I already get answered a similiar question here today, but this one is more complex.
I tried it by myself by using the general Group By Function but it is not working like I want to.
I have a table like this:
[image]

Now I would like to get a table that shows me

- Quantity based on the MAX of Key 1 and Key 2
- Latest Date with Status "A2"

Thhe result would be like:

[image]

How is this possible by using Power Query?

Comment: One of your requirements is ***Latest Date with Status "A2"***.  That being the case, why is there ***any*** result for 101?

Comment: Yes, indeed. You are right. That should be BLANK

Comment: I dont understand the requirement. You want the latest date with status A2. Fine. Then what? If Key1 is max on one row and Key2 is max on a different row (does that happen?) which row wins

Comment: You are right. Priority 1 is Key 1 and Priority 2 is Key 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly:

***Edited to correct logic flaw***
***Re-edited to correct to specifications***
***Re-edited to add some comments, and also improve data typing***

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table4"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"Order Number", Int64.Type}, 
        {"Key 1", Int64.Type}, {"Key 2", Int64.Type}, 
        {"Status", type text}, {"Quantity 1", Int64.Type},
        {"Date", type date}}),

//blank the Date if Status = A1_    
    blankDate = Table.FromRecords(Table.TransformRows(#"Changed Type", 
        (r)=> Record.TransformFields(r, {"Date", each if r[Status]="A1" then null else _})),
        type table[Order Number=Int64.Type, Key 1=Int64.Type, Key 2=Int64.Type, Quantity 1=Int64.Type, Date= Date.Type]),

//Group rows by Order Number
//then Sort by Key 1 followed by Key 2; select the first row (highest rank) for the Date and Quantity
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(blankDate, {"Order Number"}, {
        {"filtered", each Table.Sort(_,{{"Key 1", Order.Descending}, {"Key 2", Order.Descending}}){0}, type record}
    }),
    #"Expanded filtered" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "filtered", {"Quantity 1", "Date"}, {"Quantity 1", "Date"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded filtered",{{"Quantity 1", Int64.Type}, {"Date", type date}})        
in
    #"Changed Type1"
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! But why is 101 blank? There should be 80 as quantity

Comment: @joshua 101 has no A2. And you wrote it should be blank in your comment above!  Maybe you need to clarify your requirements.

Comment: Thanks for your support. I'm sorry. I mean blank just for the date. Quantity should be visible.

Comment: @joshua Also clarify that for quantity you want to Ignore the status; take the max of Key1, and use Key2 to break a tie if there are two key1's = max key1

Comment: @joshua OK, I have edited my answer so as to meet what I think are your clarified expectations.  For the date I am examining only the Status, and for the Quantity I am ignoring status, and ranking the keys.